# RAWとJPEGの違い

Tags: 画像

「RAW」「JPEG」それぞれの仕様はどこで確認できますか？
どこが決定している？

特にExifについて確認したい
Exifは独立した仕様ですか。RAWのExifとJPEGのExifの違いなど
Exifをどうやって記録している？　ヘッダー？　メタデータ？　添付ファイル？

---

**疑問に思ったきっかけ**
これまで彩度は、JPEGへ対して後からソフトウェアで調整するものだと思っていました。しかし、Wikipediaでは下記のように記載されています

> RAW画像を撮影できるカメラは、それらの設定をRAW画像に出力するが、実際の計算はパソコンで行われる

この意味が分かりませんでした。
「カメラで彩度設定した場合その設定をRAW画像に出力する、とはどういうことなのか」「(F値などの)他パラメーターと彩度におけるRAWでの取り扱われ方の違い」「そもそもRAWは画像なのか」など、色々疑問に思ったので質問しました

Comment: kunifさんが回答を書かれていますが、触れられている通りWikipediaを読めば得られる程度の質問内容に思います。わざわざ投稿されたということは、何かWikipediaでは得づらい疑問点があり、それが質問文に反映されていないのではありませんか？

Comment: jpeg,exifについては似た質問がありましたのでリンクします: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8560571/4506703

Comment: @sayuri。疑問に思ったきっかけを本文へ追記しました

Comment: @ yukihane。リンク提示ありがとうございます。「JPEG」におけるExifについては、JEIDA / CIPAによる非公式の(事実上の)標準を順守しているのですね

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipediaの記事だけでも結構な情報があるようです。

[JPEG - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)
決定しているのはここでしょう。[Overview of JPEG](https://jpeg.org/jpeg/)

> 規格書
> 規格は、合同のグループで作られたため国際標準化機構 (ISO)、国際電気標準会議 (IEC) と国際電気通信連合 (ITU) の双方から出されている。それにならい、日本産業規格 (JIS) でも規格化されている。
>
> - ITU-T勧告 T.81
> - ISO/IEC 10918-1:1994
> - JIS X 4301:1995「連続階調静止画像のディジタル圧縮及び符号処理」

[RAW画像 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAW%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F)

> 多くのファイルは標準化されていない形式である - 標準化されたRAW画像フォーマット（ISO 12234-2, TIFF/EPやDNG）はあまり使われていない。このため、将来的に保存されているデータが現像できなくなる可能性がある。また、JPEGやTIFFなどの標準化されたファイルとは違い、画像を表示できるソフトが非常に限られている。

ISO 12234-2のWikipediaには以下 TIFF/EP へのリンクだけ表示されています。
[TIFF/EP - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF/EP)

DNGはDigital Negativeというらしいです。
[Digital Negative - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Negative)

他に関連しそうなサイト
[OpenRAW - Digital Image Preservation Through Open Documentation](https://www.openraw.org/)

---

Exif
[Exchangeable image file format - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format)

> 富士フイルムが開発し、当時の日本電子工業振興協会 (JEIDA)で規格化された
>
> カメラの機種や撮影時の条件情報を画像に埋め込んでいて、ビューワやフォトレタッチソフトなどで参照、応用することができる。
>
> 対応画像形式はJPEG、TIFF、JPEG XR（HD Photo）。
>
> 記録されるメタデータ
> 以下のようなデータが記録される。
> <<以下省略>>

---

プログラミングに利用できる詳細な情報といえば、以下の規格書でしょうか。
規格書のリストと販売等のページ

[JEITA 電子情報技術産業協会/AV電子機器部門 デジタルカメラ<電子カメラ一般>関係](https://www.jeita.or.jp/cgi-bin/standard/list.cgi?cateid=1&subcateid=4)

[ISO 12234-2:2001 - Electronic still-picture imaging ... - ISO](https://www.iso.org/standard/29377.html)

[JISX4301 連続階調静止画像のディジタル圧縮及び符号処理　第１部　要件及び指針](https://www.jisc.go.jp/app/jis/general/GnrJISNumberNameSearchList?toGnrJISStandardDetailList)

---

`raw image data format 加工`とかで検索して出て来たページです。
宣伝とかも多いでしょうが、適当に選んでます。

一応、日本語のWikipedia記事の解説のセクションにも同様のことが結構詳しく書かれています。読み比べるなりしてみてください。

[RAWデータとは | RAWデータ現像・閲覧ソフト Image Data Converter サポート・お問い合わせ](https://www.sony.jp/support/software/idc/intro/raw.html)

[写真のRAW保存でデジタル現像！RAW画像とは？RAW保存の利点は？デジタル現像の勧め](https://select333.com/raw-image/)

[RAWデータとは | RAW現像の基本](https://silkypix.isl.co.jp/community/what-is-raw-data/)
[RAW現像とは？](https://silkypix.isl.co.jp/community/what-is-raw-development/#article-top)

[ホントにRAWは高画質なの？RAWとJPEGの違いとメリットデメリットをまとめてみた！](https://photo-studio9.com/raw-jpeg-difference/)

---

英語版のWikipediaにいくつか細かい情報がありました。
[Raw image format - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format)

> Image metadata which is required for inclusion in any CMS environment or database. These include the exposure settings, camera/scanner/lens model, date (and, optionally, place) of shoot/scan, authoring information and other. Some raw files contain a standardized metadata section with data in Exif format.
>
> CMS環境またはデータベースに含めるために必要な画像メタデータ。 これらには、露出設定、カメラ/スキャナー/レンズモデル、撮影/スキャンの日付（およびオプションで場所）、オーサリング情報などが含まれます。 **一部の未加工ファイルには、Exif形式のデータを含む標準化されたメタデータセクションが含まれています。**
>
> DNG, the Adobe digital negative format, is an extension of the TIFF 6.0 format and is compatible with TIFF/EP, and uses various open formats and/or standards, including Exif metadata, XMP metadata, IPTC metadata, CIE XYZ coordinates, ICC profiles, and JPEG.
>
> AdobeデジタルネガティブフォーマットであるDNGは、TIFF 6.0フォーマットの拡張であり、TIFF/EPと互換性があり、**Exifメタデータ**、XMPメタデータ、IPTCメタデータ、CIE XYZ座標、ICCプロファイルを含むさまざまなオープンフォーマットおよび/または標準を使用します 、およびJPEG。
>
> ExifTool supports the reading, writing and editing of metadata in raw image files. ExifTool supports many different types of metadata including Exif, GPS, IPTC, XMP, JFIF, GeoTIFF, ICC Profile, Photoshop IRB, FlashPix, AFCP and ID3, as well as the maker notes of many digital cameras.
>
> ExifToolは、**生の画像ファイルのメタデータの読み取り、書き込み、編集** をサポートしています。 ExifToolは、**Exif**、GPS、IPTC、XMP、JFIF、GeoTIFF、ICCプロファイル、Photoshop IRB、FlashPix、AFCP、ID3、および多くのデジタルカメラのメーカーノートなど、さまざまな種類のメタデータをサポートしています。

Comment: RAWに関して。現状では「標準化されたRAW画像フォーマット」は存在しないが、OpenRAWという統一規格が進められている。しかし、まだ完成していないし、完成したからと言って皆が従うとは限らない、という感じでしょうか？

Comment: 名目上一応存在はしているようですが、おそらく適用可能範囲が狭いのでしょう。OpenRAW～云々はそのとおりでしょうね。